# Can I code a deep learning layer without a backward function?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, layer

I want to create a layer that make two copies of the previous layer (input layer), here is my code:

```
        classdef CopyLayer < nnet.layer.Layer


        methods
        function layer = CopyLayer(numOutputs,name)
            % Set number of inputs.
            layer.NumOutputs = numOutputs;
            % Set layer name.
            layer.Name = name;
            % Set layer description.
            layer.Description = "Make " + numOutputs + ...
                " copies of the input layer";
        end

        function [varargout] = predict(X)
            % Layer forward function for prediction goes here.
            numOutputs = layer.NumOutputs;
            [h,w,c] = size(X);
            Z = zeros(h,w,c,numOutputs);
            for i= 1 : numOutputs
                Z(:,:,:,i) = X;                                            
            end
            varargout = Z;
        end

        %         function [] = backward()
        %         end
    end
    end
```

and when I try to create the layer by:

```
        layer = CopyLayer(2,'copy');
```

the following error appears:

> Abstract classes cannot be instantiated.  Class 'CopyLayer' inherits 
>           abstract methods or properties but does not implement them.
>           See the list of methods and properties that 'CopyLayer' must implement 
>           if you do not intend the class to be abstract.
>           Error in SplitLayer (line 1)
>           layer = CopyLayer(2,'copy');

and I think it's because of the no existing of backward function. Is that correct? How can I resolve this error?

Comment: @Prune thank you sir, I edited the question and did my best, my problem and code are so simple I can't give some other details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is clear -- if you're used to reading error messages, and you're familiar with abstract classes.

A class is abstract if it contains elements that are not yet defined in a manner one could instantiate.  They are intended particularly to be templates that the user can fill out to have the desired implementation details.  `nn.layer.layer` is one such abstract class.

When you instantiate an abstract class, but fail to define *every* template element, then the result is another abstract class -- just with fewer "template" elements.  That is what you've done: CopyLayer does not implement `backward`, so it's still abstract.  When you instantiate with `layer = CopyLayer(2,'copy')`, you still have open elements, so you *cannot* make a concrete object from the class.  Hence the error message.

You can work around this in a couple of ways:

1. Implement your own layer class, one that doesn't even mention a back-prop function.  You'll have extra connection work to do, since you give up your inheritance from `nn.layer`.
2. Implement `backward`, but leave the body non-functional (empty).  This will satisfy the compiler, and give you a very boring (but fast) back-prop stage.

Comment: thank you so much sir, actually i'm not familiar with abstract classes that's why the error wasn't clear for me.
the 2nd solution was easy to me and it worked. thank you again.

Comment: if you have a mathworks account I can give you the link to answer the same question so I can accept it?

Comment: Thanks, but don't worry about that.  I suggest that you simply post a link to this question on your MathWorks question.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Mr @Prune

the code after correction becomes as follow:

```
    classdef CopyLayer < nnet.layer.Layer

        properties
            % (Optional) Layer properties.
            NumOutputs

        end
   methods
        function layer = CopyLayer(numOutputs,name)
            % Set number of inputs.
            layer.NumOutputs = numOutputs;
            % Set layer name.
            layer.Name = name;
            % Set layer description.
            layer.Description = "Make " + numOutputs + ...
                " copies of the input layer";
        end

        function varargout = predict(layer,X)
            numOutputs = layer.NumOutputs;
            [h,w,c] = size(X);
            Z = zeros(h,w,c,numOutputs);
            for i= 1 : numOutputs
                Z(:,:,:,i) = X;
            end
            varargout = Z;
        end

        function [dLdX] = backward(~,~,~,~,~)
        end
    end
    end
```